# Internet Explorer doesn't update label by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have this odd problem, I will try to describe as specific as possible.

I'm developing a web module with ASP.NET 4.0, jQuery and with the use of Ajax I have getters and setters to the web server.

I have a product selector, when selecting a product, I will get the data with an Ajax call. I modify than in the details pane the product name, the images, desription,...

It works fine in FireFox and Chrome, but in Internet Explorer, the product name (and only the product name - images and description, coming from the same object work) refuses to update.

When I place a line break in Visual Studio and I wait for some seconds and hit F5 (I see the correct product name) the label is changed. But when I hit really fast on F5, it is not. So, I placed an `setTimeout()` code with a delay of 50 milliseconds, and that works for IE.

Anyone know why this behaviour is occuring in Internet Explorer?

Some code:

```
success: function (msg) {
        $("#tblHardwareOptions tr").remove();
        var tempDevice = JSON.parse(msg.d[3]);

        $("#imgDevice").attr("src", tempDevice.image);
        $("#deviceDescription").html(unescape(tempDevice.description));
        //=> setTimeOut works, added the "" to be sure it is empty
        //            setTimeout(
        //                function () {
        //without timeout it won't work in IE, even emptying the string
        //                    $(lblMachineName).text("");
        //                    $(lblMachineName).text(unescape(tempDevice.modelname));
        //                }
        //            , 50);
        //Tried without jQuery, but doesn't work neither
        document.getElementById(lblMachineName.replace("#", "")).innerText = unescape(tempDevice.modelname);
```

Comment: just wondering, why is your selector like this: $(lblMachineName)? what is lblMachineName here? is it a jQuery object?

Comment: It is a string variable. I use seperate js files and the control id's are resolved on the main page. In the beginning of the project I chose AutoID (default) as ClientIDMode and I stick to this now. Doesn't really bother me, altough mvc would be better in the long run :-)

Comment: And that is why I have to do a replace with # because I prefix # when I resolve the control ID's. But anyhow, that is not the issue I think.